# Print results in console of class

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to OOPython and am trying to simply execute the value of `parse_param_paths()` to get the value of `dictpath`

I have:

```
class Injection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tld_object = None
        self.path_object = None 
        print "Class Initialized"

    def gather_path(self):
        self.path_object = PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(FKtoTld=3)
        return self.path_object

    def parse_param_paths(self):
        if self.path_object is not None:
            dictpath = {}
            for path in self.path_object:
                self.params = path.split("?")[1].split("&")
                out = list(map(lambda v: v.split("=")[0] +"=" + self.fuzz_vectors, self.params))
                dictpath[path] = out
            print dictpath
```

Any help is greatly appreciated here. Thank you

Comment: Injection().parse_param_paths()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from myapp import Injection

inj = Injection() # create an instance 

inj.gather_path() # to set self.object to a value other than None

inj.parse_param_paths() # call method with instance
```

Put a  `print self.path_object is not None` before `if self.path_object is not None`

If `self.path_object`  is `None` you won't get any output as the condition won't  evaluate to  `True` so you won't execute anymore lines in your method.

Comment: from myapp import Injection

Comment: When I run this, the method isnt outputting anything - is something glaringly wrong with the output of parse_param_paths() ?

Comment: I wonder why it is evaluating to false though, I tried outputting the value of self.path_object() within gather_path() method and it showed all the paths . Any other tips?

Comment: I added code, you need to set self.object to a value

Comment: good call with instantiating gather_path(), when I then ran parse_param_paths(), it said AttributeError: 'PathsOfDomain' object has no attribute 'split' ... which makes sense, as I'm trying to use the native .split() method to parse a path beginning at ? and each place and '=' sign occurs and '&' symbol - how can I deal with that? Thanks a lot for your help so far

Comment: If this is Django, you can use get etc.. to get content, you should be able to use something like that . You need to get the string/text from the object.